# Treeview - How to add a child node dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf

basically I'm trying to port this working Winforms code into a WPF application.

What it does is to add a child node to an existing parent node:

```
string ingredient = oranges;
string cookingSuggestion = pie;    

if (treeView1.Nodes.ContainsKey(ingredient))
{
    treeView1.Nodes[ingredient].Nodes.Add(cookingSuggestion);
}
```

However I'm not being able to fully translate it to WPF:

```
string ingredient = oranges;
string cookingSuggestion = pie;

if (treeView1.Items.Cast<TreeViewItem>().Any(item => item.Header.ToString() == ingredient))
{
    TreeViewItem childItem = new TreeViewItem { Header = cookingSuggestion };
    ingredient.Items.Add(childItem);    
}
```

The if statement works: it can tell that the parent node exists in the TreeView.

Next, it creates the child node, no problem there too.

But, finally, I cannot add the child node underneath that existing parent node, because *ingredient* is a string (the red underline is showing under "Items", in the last statement)

The error is: *'string' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no accessible extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Of course it is a string; you've declared it so. Shouldn't you do `treeView1.Items.Add()`?

Comment: @Sach Unfortunately if I do "treeView1.Items.Add(childItem)", it doesn't add the child node under the parent node.

Comment: If you are converting it to WPF, i would suggest you to use MVVM, create a viewmodel and have the collection of items in the viewmodel and bind it to the TreeView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var item = treeView1.Items.Cast<TreeViewItem>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.Header.ToString() == ingredient);
if (item != null)
{
    TreeViewItem childItem = new TreeViewItem { Header = cookingSuggestion };
    item.Items.Add(childItem);    
}
```

Comment: It works as long as the var "Item" is renamed to something else (otherwise it won't compile)! I've edited your answer just to replace "var item" with "var parentItem" in order to fix that detail. Thank you a lot!